# Formset not showing label in django

Tags: html, css, django, django-models, django-forms

I am developing a domestic worker booking app in django
When I try to pass the formset, I am not geting the label of that field. I am only getting the field in html.

```
 {% for formset in formsets %}
<form method="post">
{% for form in formset %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div>
            <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            {{ field }}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p>{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

This the html code

```
def staffApply(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_domestic_works = request.POST.getlist('domestic_works')
        formsets = []
        if 'cook' in selected_domestic_works:
            formsets.append(CookingForm(request.POST,prefix='cook'))
        if 'driver' in selected_domestic_works:
            formsets.append(DriverForm(request.POST,prefix='driver'))
        print(formsets)
        return render(request, 'staffApply2.html', {'formsets': formsets})
    return render(request,'staffapply.html',{'uid':pk})
    enter code here
```

This is my views.py

```
class CookingForm(ModelForm):
    food_cooked=(('veg','veg'),
    ('non-veg','non-veg'),
    ('both','both')
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Cook
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude=['user']
        widgets={
            'food_cooked':forms.widgets.RadioSelect(),
    'type_of_cuisine':forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }
```

This is my forms.py
I am getting the fields to type. But I am not getting hte label for those fields. Please help me fix this.

```
class Cook(models.Model):
    food_cooked=(('veg','veg'),
    ('non-veg','non-veg'),
    ('both','both')
    )
    type_of_cuisine=(('NorthIndian','NorthIndian'),
    ('SouthIndian','SouthIndian'),
    ('Chettinadu','Chettinadu'),
    ('Chinese','Chinese'),
    )

    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food_cooked=models.CharField(choices=food_cooked,max_length=30)
    type_of_cuisine=models.CharField(choices=type_of_cuisine,max_length=30)
    experience=models.IntegerField()
    wages_expected=models.IntegerField()
    dishwashing_flag=models.BooleanField()
    wages_for_dishwashing=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    desc=models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

This is my models.py

Comment: Can you display your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one extra loop, with the wrong naming so you cannot access `{{ field.label }}` on your loops its like you are trying something like `{{ form.field.attribute.label }}`, the correct way would be the following:

```
{% for form in formsets %}
    <form method="post">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div>
                <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                {{ field }}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p>{{ error }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, you can also use Django [form rendering options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options), instead of doing it manually.

```
{% for form in formsets %}
    <form method="post">
        {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro....It worked...I have been wondering what is wrong for a long time